# changing directories and opening files

Tags: command-line

For an example, I am in the directory `Desktop`. I then do `cd break` and when I list all files in break, i have for example `main.cpp` file. I am trying to be able to go straight from Desktop to opening up `main.cpp` using sublime text(using `subl` to open it) without getting to `break` then doing `subl main.cpp` but can't seem to figure it out. This is what I want to do:

```
/Desktop $ cd break/subl main.cpp
```

but obviously that won't work. How do I do this and combine everything into one command?

Comment: `subl break/main.cpp`? Or, to explain more clearly, put the command you use to open the file at the start of the path.

Comment: that was easy enough, thanks!! could never figure it out so I would always **ls** then open it

Comment: @Zanna post is as answer please

Comment: @Kdrumz just FYI you don't have to `cd` into folder, you can specify full path. If  you need  to `cd` somewhere that is very deep into directory tree, just make a bash function and place it into `.bashrc` or  make a symlink to that directory. Just friendly advice

Comment: I can't post as answer? I don't see how to.  ahh okay, thanks @Serg !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open a file with a specific program in a directory other than the current working directory, put the command you use to open the file first, then the path to the file. In your case:

```
subl break/main.cpp
```

You can also use an absolute path, which will work regardless of the current working directory

```
subl ~/Desktop/break/main.cpp
```

You can use wildcards in the path. For example I have a file in

```
/home/zanna/Dropbox/Writings/journal02/Capoeira
```

I open it like this

```
vim ~/Dr*/Wr*/j*2/Cap*
```

If you often open a specific file with a particular program you could make an alias to open it

```
alias capedit='vim ~/Dropbox/Writings/journal02/Capoeira'
```

As [@Serg suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870955/changing-directories-and-opening-files/870957#comment1350274_870955) you can also make a symlink to a file buried deep in a directory tree to make it more accessible

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/Writings/journal02/Capoeira ~/new-writing/Capoeira
```

Now I can just

```
vim ~/new-writing/Capoeira
```

Comment: I would suggest tab completion rather than wildcards for this task. It's easier to figure out what is going on if something is not as planned (missing directory, more than one completion...), and it is an useful shortcut in a wider range of cases.

Comment: `~/` is not absolute, its relative home directory.

Comment: @DmitryMiksIr it is an absolute path, it just uses tilde expansion - that doesn't make it relative (except to the current user of the shell), because it works anywhere in the filesystem

Comment: Yep, you are right.